# Unity GUI.Label/GUI.Box blackout images

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I draw images from GUI.Label/GUI.Box but Unity driwed use "blackout" (or "red filter") before render images.
https://i.gyazo.com/255e4947a7ca95f835104a1f8ffa2e61.png

In screen right original apple - bright. In left apple be drawed unity, but this dark.

I used **GUI.Color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,1f)** but it didn't help me

Next, a write editor (editor windows) and draw this:

https://i.gyazo.com/06908720a2b00c538558c61092a98329.png

Apples were dark. It's my ItemDrawService:

```
public class ItemDrawService {

    private GUIStyle labelStyle = null;

        public ItemDrawService(GUIStyle labelStyle){
            this.labelStyle=labelStyle;
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Отрисовка предмета в инвентаре
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Рисуемый предмет</param>
    /// <param name="offsetX">Смещение (позиция) инвентаря по x</param>
    /// <param name="offsetY">Смещение (позиция) инвентаря по y</param>
    /// <param name="fixWebPosition">при fixWebPosition=true предмет рисуется "в сетке"</param>
    /// <param name="drawIcon">при drawIcon=false, предмет рисуется без иконки</param>
    public void DrawItem(ItemSlot item, float offsetX, float offsetY, bool fixWebPosition = true, bool drawIcon = true){

        Rect cellRectangle;

        if (fixWebPosition) {

            cellRectangle = new Rect(offsetX + CellSettings.cellPaddingX + (item.position.X - 1) * CellSettings.cellWidth,
                                     offsetY + CellSettings.cellPaddingY + (item.position.Y - 1) * CellSettings.cellHeight,
                                     CellSettings.cellWidth,
                                     CellSettings.cellHeight);

        } else {

            cellRectangle = new Rect(offsetX,
                                     offsetY,
                                     CellSettings.cellWidth,
                                     CellSettings.cellHeight);

        }

        if (drawIcon)
            labelStyle.normal.background = item.item.resource.icon;

        string description = item.item.getCount()>1? item.item.getCount().ToString()+CLang.getInstance().get(Dictionary.K_COUNT) : "";

        GUI.color = new Color(1f,1f,1f,1f);
        GUI.Label(cellRectangle, description, labelStyle);

    }


}
```

How I do the drawing intact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this in [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LinearLighting.html):

> **Legacy GUI and Linear Authored Textures**
>
> Rendering elements of the Legacy GUI System is always done in gamma
>   space. This means that, for the legacy GUI system, GUI textures should
>   not have their gamma removed on read. This can be achieved in two
>   ways:
>
> - **Set the texture type to GUI in the texture importer**
> - **Check the ‘Bypass sRGB Sampling’ checkbox in the advanced texture importer**